# How to set background color of a cell to 'No-fill' in XlsxWriter library

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Here's a scenario from my code:

```
bgNum = [0,0,0,36,35,0,36]
for bgNumIdx, bgNumVal in enumerate(bgNum):
    if bgNumVal == 36:
        format.set_bg_color('yellow')
    else:
        #set bg color to no-fill
```

Else statement should set background-color to no-fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some trial and error, this is what I got:

```
cell_format.set_bg_color(False)
```

Comment: I tried cell_format.set_bg_color(None) bt silly me didn't try 'False'. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I didn't think of `False` too unitill I see `cell_format.set_bold(False)  # Turns bold off.` from [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html). Anyway, glad to help.